# Execute mysql query one after the other inside for loop in node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I am trying to perform multiple SQL queries inside a for loop one after the other. What I am trying to achieve is that each iteration will use the output generated by the previous iteration query to generate a new query and execute it, but what happens is that due to the asynchronous nature of I/O in javascript, all the queries are getting executed all at once and throwing error as the result from the previous query is undefined as it's not yet executed.

My syntax is similar to this:-

```
var iterationCount = 10;
var query = "Initial SQL query";
for(i=0;i<iterationCount;i++) {
    result = executeSQLQuery(query);

    query = createQueryFromresult(result);
}

function executeSQLQuery(query) {
  // logic to execute the query
  return result;
}

function createQueryFromresult(result) {
  // logic to create a query by fetching some fields from the result 
  // depending upon some conditions
  return query;
}
```

Comment: That's an unfortunate problem, but how do you expect us to suggest suitable changes to your code, if you don't show the code? Please show enough of your code to allow us to understand/reproduce the issue. Thanks. (however as a general suggestion, I'd say that if the method you're calling to run the query returns a Promise, you can chain that promise to the next one to make the execution sequential. Or at least, you could run the next query from inside the callback for the previous one, rather than using a simple loop.)

Comment: could you please show us some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is with async / await. Notice that the `await` syntax lets you use asynchronous method codes in a sequence in an easy-to-read form.  Also notice that you can await a function that returns a promise, or you can await an async function. They're actually the same thing with slightly different syntax.

Something like this.

```
 /* promisified query method, suitable for await */
 function doQuery(conn,sql,args) {
     return new Promise (function( resolve, reject ) {
        conn.query(sql, args, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) return reject(error)
            resolve({results, fields})
        }) 
     })
 }

 /* your loop operation */
 async function whatever ( args ) {
      for (whatever conditions) {
         let queryOutput = await doQuery (conn, sql, [arg, arg])
         let firstColumn = queryOutput.results['first_column']
      }
      return resultValue
 }

 /* call your async function */
 whatever(args)
 .next (function (resultValue) {  whatever you need } )
 .catch (console.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use forEach loop like

```
array.forEach(async item=>{
  await conn.query(sql, args)
  //write query with await
}
```

Comment: You can't use `forEach` to do sequential async operations.